# Can't work out how matrix is applied to 2D vertices

Tags: 2d, mathematics, textures, matrix

I have a texture, some 2D vertices, and a matrix. The matrix is used to calculate the texture coordinates for each vertex, but the problem is that the matrix comes with absolutely no documentation and I'm having trouble working out how to calculate the texture coords correctly. I have it partially working.

The matrix is in this format:

```
sx rx tx
ry sy ty
```

Where `s` means "scale", `r` means "rotate", and `t` means "translate".

If the matrix doesn't contain any rotation (i.e. `ry = rx = 0`), I can correctly calculate the texture coordinates `u` and `v` like this:

```
u = x/sx - tx
v = y/sy - ty
```

But I can't figure out how to put `rx` and `ry` into the equation and get the correct results. Normal matrix multiplication involves multiplying and adding but this one involves dividing and subtracting, so I know I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.

Here is one of the matrices with rotation:

```
26.191574096679688   7.0180206298828125  1579
-7.0180206298828125  26.191574096679688  1879
```

Here is one of the matrices without rotation:

```
27.115478515625  0                1867
0                27.115478515625  800
```

Comment: For 2D coordinates with rotations you need a 3x3 matrix, not a 3x2 matrix. So where's the last part? :)

Comment: It's assumed to be `0, 0, 1` I guess.

Comment: Plus, rotation only requires a 2x2 matrix. Translation requires a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: It is x*sx not x/sx, and it is +tx*1 not -tx*1  you might want to lookup matrix vector multiplication on wikipedia

Comment: @Maik that gives incorrect results. It's not a straight matrix multiplication. Please read the question before commenting.

Comment: @Tom if that operations gives you the right results, then the matrix is wrong, probably you have the inverse matrix of the matrix you actually want. How did you create that matrix?

Comment: @Maik I didn't create the matrix, it was loaded from an SWF file. You are probably right, it looks like it might be the inverse. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom in the meantime, could you post that matrix?

Comment: @Maik I've added two of them to the bottom of the question.

Comment: thx @Tom, in case you dont have it yet, this is the inverse matrix of the first example:

Comment: `0.0356226228   -0.0095450654  -38.3129425048`

Comment: `0.0095450654   0.0356226228   -82.0065689086`  can you try it using normal matrix vector multiplication?

Comment: I just tried that inverse matrix, and it's coming out 100% correct. Thanks. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: great to hear that @Tom, I'll post it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As analyzed in the comments, the matrix was the inverse matrix. Inverting it gives the correct results. Here is the first example from the question:

```
scale = 27.115515  rot = -15 deg   trans = {1579, 1879}

26.191574096679688   7.0180206298828125  1579
-7.0180206298828125  26.191574096679688  1879
```

the inverse matrix to use is:

```
0.0356226228  -0.0095450654   -38.3129425048
0.0095450654   0.0356226228   -82.0065689086
```